Using timeout and parallel in operations with DB
I have implemented a code that does several operations on the DB. Now I have decided to parallelize it to improve performance. To do this I have changed all asynchronous operations to synchronous, and this has caused me a problem.
Everything related to the transaction that the code encapsulates, when it becomes synchronous, does not allow the use of a token to define a timeout of the transaction.
Previously, without parallelization, to the context.database.BeginTransactionAsync and similar, you could pass a CancellationTokenSource, which would cause an exception to be generated any time the assigned time was exceeded.
Now, without using asynchronous operations, the context.database.BeginTransaction and similar, does not allow a CancellationTokenSource to be passed as a parameter, so I have lost the transaction timeout feature. Do you have any idea how I can recover this feature? I have read about using a timer, or a Task, but neither of the two options convince me. Do you have any other ideas?
You can check out a summary of my code below to get a better idea of what I'm telling you.
Parallel.ForEach(excelRawList.SuccessRows, options, (excelRow) =>
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString
            ("connectionstring")).Options))
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(dbContext))
        {
            unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                int? decision = CanBeInserted(unitOfWork, excelRow.id);

                if (decision != 0)
                {
                    if (!excelRow.Store)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            if (decision != null)
                            {
                                service3.MoveToBackup(unitOfWork, decision.Value);
                            }

                            Entity2 entity2ToBeInserted = service1.changeExcelRowToEntity2(excelRow);

                            excelRow.Entity2 = entity2ToBeInserted;
                            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity2>().Add(entity2ToBeInserted);
                            unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity1>().Add(excelRow);

                            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

                            unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();
                            
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();

                            excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() {"Timeout ended"});
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();

                            excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() {"Exception"});
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        excelRow.FK_Entity1_Entity2 = null;
                        unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity1>().Add(excelRow);
                        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
                        unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() {"Repeated"});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() {"Exception"});
            }
        }
    }
});

-- UPDATED --
Well, following the recommendations of another user. I have tried using the Parallel.ForEachAsync function, but it didn't work either.
This function allows you to define a CancellationToken in the lambda, but not a CancellationTokenSource, which in my case, is what I need, because this way I can define the duration of the token.
If I create this CancellationTokenSource outside the ForEachAsync, I have no visibility of it inside the ForEachAsync.
If I define this CancellationTokenSource inside the ForEachAsync, no iteration works.
Reading the documentation, I found this definition very promising, but it is not actually generating any duration on the token.
CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource(_timeoutTransaccion);
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(excelRawList.SuccessRows, token.Token, async (excelRow, cts) => 

Well, hoping provide you the tools to help me.

Related: Stopping a task without a CancellationToken. Spoiler alert, you can't.

After fixing the cancellation-related problems, I would be very interested to know if the parallelization had any positive effect to the performance of the database operations. If I had to bet my money, I would bet that it didn't.

Hi @TheodorZoulias. Many thanks for helping here. Yep, it is working completely. Not using parallelization last 50 seconds average, using parallelization - 2 threads but without timeout for transaction - last 20 seconds average. I have checked the links provided for you and people is saying could work, but I only see the things I am doing without any result. Maybe I am doing something wrong. What do you think to use a timer at the beginning of the transaction? Many Thanks again

You can't inject cancellation behavior to an operation that was never designed to be canceled. If I understand correctly, in your case you do have cancellable APIs to call, but these APIs are asynchronous and your context is synchronous. Just call them synchronously. There is always a way to call an asynchronous API synchronously. If you want cancellation, just don't bother with APIs that don't support cancellation. You are losing your time if you do.

@TheodorZoulias. I am trying to cancel a Transaction agaisnt DDBB. That code works when I am not using parallelization. But, if I use it, I cannot raise an OperationCancelledException when duration is overpassed. My point here, if I can define a working timeout for the transaccion without parallel, I should be able to do it the same using parallelization If I keep safe-tread property enabled.

To be honest I am confused, and the reason is probably that I haven't read you question carefully and thoroughly. There is a block of code in the question that is hard to read, because it is high and wide enough to cause both a vertical and a horizontal scrollbar to appear. This alone greatly disincentivizes me to read your question thoroughly. It's not fun to have to juggle with two scrollbars, just to read some code.

Apart from that, I am not sure what this code represents. Is it your initial sequential approach that enabled cancellation but lacked performance, or your second parallel attempt that enabled performance but lacked cancellation? If it's the second, most like it would be more helpful to show us your first approach instead of the second. It's easier to give you guidance about how to parallelize correctly working code, than to help you fix the problems of a failed parallelization attempt.

You can still do it - use the Parallel.ForEachAsync (available since .NET 6) which allows using async function bodies. Something along these lines:
CancellationToken  = ...;
Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    new[] { new object() },
    new ParallelOptions(),
    async (excelRow, ct) =>
    {
        // ...
        // ct is linked with the someCt passed to the Parallel.ForEachAsync
        await using var tran = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(ct);
        // ...
    },
    someCt);


Hi Guru. Many thanks for helping here. Your solution looks quite good, but but I can't get it to work. I tried this code Parallel.ForEachAsync(excelRawList.SuccessRows, options, async (excelRow, cts) =>. I need a CancellationTokenSource because let me define the duration of the token. But whatever I do or how I define the CancellationTokenSource, when I enter in the ForEachAsync, the cts var is just a CancellationToken. I have no idea how to get a CancellationTokenSource inside of ForEachAsync. Would you mind helping me? Many Thanks again.

@Kenzo_Gilead can you please provide a full [mre]?

I you want I can provided one, but it doesnt provide more information. Parallel.ForEachAsync, per definition, uses a CancellationToken, but I need something with the same behavior of a CancellationTokenSource. I mean, I want to define a lifetime or duration time for the token. Why? because I have a few operations in DB, all of them as part of a transaction. If, for some reason, some of these operations, take too long, the whole transaction will be canceled and an exception is generated.

@Kenzo_Gilead "I have no idea how to get a CancellationTokenSource inside of ForEachAsync" - either I don't understand the problem or you can just capture (use) the CancellationTokenSource variable inside the handler lambda.

Hi @GuruStron. I didnt know if I get your point here. Basically, the ct you defined in the lambda must be a CancellationToken, but I need a CancellationTokenSource that let me define a duration for it. If I define a CancellationTokenSource outside of the Parallel.ForEachAsync I will not have visibility of it within ForEachAsync. If I define it inside the ForEachAsync is not working at all. And, If I use await Parallel.ForEachAsync(excelRawList.SuccessRows, token.Token, async (excelRow, cts), the duration of the token is not working. I will update my question, but thank you anyway.

Finally got it and It took me a lot to find the solution. I am posting here how I fix it hoping can help to another people in similar situations.
A code that performs 2 insertions in DDBB in the best case, and up to 4 insertions and 2 deletions in the worst case. We want to parallelize this code to improve performance and reduce processing time. But at the same time we want to maintain the features already present, such as: encapsulating everything in a transaction within a unit of work and having a timeout to carry out that transaction.
The final idea has been to use a timer with its elapsed event activated so that it sets a TaskCompletionSource to true. Subsequently, we will wait for what ends first, the timer or the operations in DDBB. If it is the timer, an OperationCancelledException will be thrown and collected later. Below I show you a schematic of the code.
Besides, using Parallel.ForEachAsync instead of Parallel.ForEach
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(excelRawList.SuccessRows, options, async (excelRow, _) =>
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString
            ("connectionstring")).Options))
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(dbContext))
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(_timeoutTransaccion);
            var timerTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            try
            {
                timer.AutoReset = false;

                timer.Start();

                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    timerTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
                };
                unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();


                int? decision = CanBeInserted(unitOfWork, excelRow.id);

                if (decision != 0)
                {
                    if (!excelRow.Store)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timerTaskCompletionSource.Task, Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                return await CoreTaskOperationsDDBB(decision, unitOfWork, excelRow);
                            })).ConfigureAwait(false);

                            if (completedTask == timerTaskCompletionSource.Task)
                            {
                                throw new OperationCanceledException();
                            }
                            else if (completedTask is Task<ExcelError> taskWithErrorResult)
                            {
                                var result = await taskWithErrorResult;
                                excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(result);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();

                            excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() { "Timeout ended" });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            unitOfWork.Rollback();

                            excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() { "Exception" });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        excelRow.FK_Entity1_Entity2 = null;
                        unitOfWork.Context.Set<Entity1>().Add(excelRow);
                        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
                        unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() { "Repeated" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excelRawList.ErrorRows.Add(new ExcelError() { "Exception" });
            }
        }
    }
});


The System.Timers.Timer+TaskCompletionSource shenanigans is just a worse version of the existing API WaitAsync (.NET 8). Which I assume that you could use, since you have tagged the question with the .net-8.0 tag. Besides that, neither the WaitAsync nor your approach does what you expect it to do. It doesn't cancel the asynchronous operation itself. It just cancel the waiting of the operation. The operation keeps running (as fire-and-forget), consuming resources and keeping the database busy.

Wow, it looks like exactly I want. Do you mind to provide an example or similar? I want to test it and rate the answer in consequence. Many thanks as usual @TheodorZoulias

Honestly I don't think that this question is in need of more answers. It's more in need of clarification and curation.
